# Trying to understand the time complexity of this dynamic recursive subset sum

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic, time-complexity, subset-sum

```
# Returns true if there exists a subsequence of `A[0…n]` with the given sum
def subsetSum(A, n, k, lookup):
 
    # return true if the sum becomes 0 (subset found)
    if k == 0:
        return True
 
    # base case: no items left, or sum becomes negative
    if n < 0 or k < 0:
        return False
 
    # construct a unique key from dynamic elements of the input
    key = (n, k)
 
    # if the subproblem is seen for the first time, solve it and
    # store its result in a dictionary
    if key not in lookup:
 
        # Case 1. Include the current item `A[n]` in the subset and recur
        # for the remaining items `n-1` with the decreased total `k-A[n]`
        include = subsetSum(A, n - 1, k - A[n], lookup)
 
        # Case 2. Exclude the current item `A[n]` from the subset and recur for
        # the remaining items `n-1`
        exclude = subsetSum(A, n - 1, k, lookup)
 
        # assign true if we get subset by including or excluding the current item
        lookup[key] = include or exclude
 
    # return solution to the current subproblem
    return lookup[key]
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # Input: a set of items and a sum
    A = [7, 3, 2, 5, 8]
    k = 14
 
    # create a dictionary to store solutions to subproblems
    lookup = {}
 
    if subsetSum(A, len(A) - 1, k, lookup):
        print('Subsequence with the given sum exists')
    else:
        print('Subsequence with the given sum does not exist')
```

It is said that the complexity of this algorithm is O(n * sum), but I can't understand how or why;
can someone help me? Could be a wordy explanation or a recurrence relation, anything is fine

Comment: Yikes.  It's definitely O(n * k), but I'm not sure how to prove it.  Good question!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation I can give is to realize that when `lookup[(n, k)]` has a value, it is True or False and indicates whether some subset of `A[:n+1]` sums to `k`.

Imagine a naive algorithm that just fills in all the elements of lookup row by row.

`lookup[(0, i)]` (for 0 ≤ `i` ≤ `total`) has just two elements true, `i = A[0]` and `i = 0`, and all the other elements are false.

`lookup[(1, i)]` (for 0 ≤ `i` ≤ `total`) is true if `lookup[(0, i)]` is true or `i ≥ A[1]` and `lookup[(0, i - A[1])` is true.  I can reach the sum `i` either by using `A[i]` or not, and I've already calculated both of those.

...
`lookup[(r, i)]` (for 0 ≤ `i` ≤ `total`) is true if `lookup[(r - 1, i)]` is true or `i ≥ A[r]` and `lookup[(r - 1, i - A[r])` is true.

Filling in this table this way, it is clear that we can completely fill the lookup table for rows `0 ≤ row < len(A)` in time `len(A) * total` since filling in each element in linear.  And our final answer is just checking if `(len(A) - 1, sum)` True in the table.

Your program is doing the exact same thing, but calculating the value of entries of `lookup` as they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for submitting two answers.  I think I came up with a slightly simpler explanation.

Take your code in imagine putting the three lines inside `if key not in lookup:` into a separate function, `calculateLookup(A, n, k, lookup)`.  I'm going to call "the cost of calling `calculateLookup` for `n` and `k` for a specific value of `n` and `k` to be the total time spent in the call to `calculateLookup(A, n, k, loopup)`, but **excluding** any recursive calls to `calculateLookup`.

The key insight is that as defined above, the cost of calling `calculateLookup()` for any `n` and `k` is O(1).  Since we are excluding recursive calls in the cost, and there are no for loops, the cost of `calculateLookup` is the cost of just executing a few tests.

The entire algorithm does a fixed amount of work, calls `calculateLookup`, and then a small amount of work.  Hence the amount of time spent in our code is the same as asking how many times do we call `calculateLookup`?

Now we're back to previous answer.  Because of the lookup table, every call to `calculateLookup` is called with a different value for `(n, k)`.  We also know that we check the bounds of `n` and `k` before each call to `calculateLookup` so `1 ≤ k ≤ sum` and `0 ≤ n ≤ len(A)`.  So `calculateLookup` is called at most `(len(A) * sum)` times.

---

In general, for these algorithms that use memoization/cacheing, the easiest thing to do is to separately calculate and then sum:

1. How long things take assuming all values you need are cached.
2. How long it takes to fill the cache.

The algorithm you presented is just filling up the `lookup` cache.  It's doing it in an unusual order, and its not filling every entry in the table, but that's all its doing.

---

The code would be slightly faster with

```
lookup[key] =  subsetSum(A, n - 1, k - A[n], lookup) or subsetSum(A, n - 1, k, lookup)
```

Doesn't change the O() of the code in the worst case, but can avoid some unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Never heard back from OP.  Does this answer your question?